# passing data from fragment to activity

Tags: android

I have an activity that contains a fragment. On a click on the actionbar it should create a new fragment with a sting[] from the first activity.

I pass the data to the new fragment with setArguments() and a bundle when I start it from the Activity.
the Problem is, I can't pass the String[] from the first Fragment to the Activity respectively access it.
I tried doing it with a method that returns the string[]. 
And accessed it in the Activity:

FirstFragment ff = new FirstFragment();
ff.getstring();

but it was empty (null)

so is there a other/better possibility?

thx

**Edit:**

Activity contains firstFragment
actionbarButton (in activity) starts newFragment (replaces firstFragment) and the String[] gets passed to Activity and then with setArguments to newFragment

Answer (score 0):

in your fragment, you can access its parent activity using:

```
FirstActivity fActivity= (FirstActivity)getActivity();
String[] data = fActivity.getMyArray();
```

now you have the data, and you can pass them to the new `Activity\Fragment`